# Changing ngForOf to get Iterable from Behaviour Subject

Tags: angular, directive, angular2-directives

for my App I want to have a directive like ngForOf (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts) but instead of getting the iterable object from Input() I want to get from a Behavior Subject in the directive Class.

Using the Behavior Subject in the Host class like:

```
BehaviourSubject.subscribe((value) => {this.items = value})

<comp ngFor="let item of item"></comp>
```

is not a option. Instead, I want to start the subscription in the directive.

I want to use the directive like this:

```
 <comp *ngFor></comp>
```

Any ideas to make this work? (Changes from the ngForCode)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but to give you an idea:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[forBs]'
})
export class ForBs<T> extends NgForOf<T> {

  @Input()
  forBs: BehaviorSubject<NgIterable<T>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  get ngForOf(): NgIterable<T> {
    return this.forBs.getValue();
  }

  constructor(_viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, _template: TemplateRef<NgForOfContext<T>>, _differs: IterableDiffers) {
    super(_viewContainer, _template, _differs);
  }
}
```

This will probably not have template, and trackBy support.. and perhaps some other issues with the `onChanges` and `doCheck` hooks. But then again, this will help you get on the right track.

Usage will be like this:

```
<comp *forBs="item$"></comp>
```

Where

```
item$ = new BehaviourSubject([]);
```

But then again, you can also just use the `async` pipe ;)

```
<comp *ngFor="let item of item$ | async"></comp>
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer, but still using  @Input(). The usage should be <comp *forBs></comp>

Comment: @dindunuffin no it should not, because you use the `*` in front of it. If you check the source code of `*ngFor`, you can also see that the @Input is on `ngForOf`

Comment: You want `*forBs="items$"`?

Comment: I want <comp *forBS> and like 

constructor(....){
BehaviourSubject.subscribe((value) => this.myIterableObejct=value)
}

Comment: But how will you be able to pass the subject to the directive? You need some binding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172077/discussion-between-dindunuffin-and-pierreduc).

Comment: e.g from DOM 

if (parentElementRef === viewContainer._view.nodes[i].renderElement && viewContainer._view.nodes[i + 1].instance !== undefined) { 
console.log(viewContainer._view.nodes[i + 1]); 
return viewContainer._view.nodes[i + 1]; 
}